# Draw choropleth map for US states using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have json file for us states boundaries from here: [https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_5m.json'](https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_5m.json%27)

Also I have information about population of US states in df_state (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12_4mOvF3skwWcIG_LojC07UOpjXPjhN9dRcqb6kxYck/edit?usp=sharing), that looks like this:

| NAME | april | 2020 | Total Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | 5,024,279 | 5,024,803 | 5,039,877 |
| Alaska | 733,391 | 732,441 | 732,673 |
| Arizona | 7,151,502 | 7,177,986 | 7,276,316 |

Based on these two sources, I decided to draw a choropleth map on plotly that would draw US states and color them based on total population:

```
geo_states='https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_5m.json'
with urlopen(geo_states) as response:
    geo_states= json.load(response)

df_state=pd.read_csv('state.csv')
df_state['Total Population']=df_state['Total Population'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
    
fig_states = px.choropleth_mapbox(df_state, 
                                   geojson=geo_states,
                                   locations='NAME',
                                   featureidkey='properties.NAME',
                                   color='Total Population',
                                   color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                                   mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                                   opacity=0.3
                                   )
fig_states.update_layout(autosize=False, height=600, width=1000, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}) 
fig_states.show()
```

But i got blank return:
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: The lack of a center setting on the map indicated the west coast of Africa in the Atlantic Ocean. So if you set the latitude and longitude of the center and the zoom to 3, it will show correctly. `center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129}, zoom=3,`

Comment: Also, Plotly has built-in State geometries so you don't need an external JSON https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries